# angular, correct way for a function callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, asynchronous

I am writing an `ItemProvider` for my app in angular js.
I chose a service.

```
app.factory('ItemProvider', function($http) {
  var url = "http://localhost:7888/api.php/json?";

  return {
    get_data: function() {          
      $http.get(url).
        success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
          json = data;
          console.log("app returned ok");
          console.log(json);
          callback(json);
        }).

        error(function(data,status,headers,config) {
          console.log("Error getting data from app!");
          json = data;
          callback(json);
        });

      callback = function(json) {
        console.log("callback");
        return json;
      }
      console.log("already done");
    }
  };
});
```

Of course what happens here is that `get_data` returns immediately before the actual calls to the backend via `$http` returned...

How do I correctly have a `get_data` function which will return the data from the backend? I tried adding a callback (see code above) but I realize by the time it's getting called, `get_data` already finished as well...

Comment: *"How do I correctly have a get_data function which will return the data from the backend?"* that isn't possible. `get_data` will either have to accept a callback, or return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$http is hardcoded to only work asynchronously, meaning your only option is to code with that in mind. Due to this, it isn't possible for get_data to directly return the data, instead, it has to either accept a callback, or return a promise. The promise route is far easier *in my opinion*.

```
app.factory('ItemProvider', function($http) {
  var url = "http://localhost:7888/api.php/json?";

  return {
    get_data: function(url) {          
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  };
});
```

example usage:

```
//...
ItemProvider.get_data('/items')
  .success(function (items) {
    console.log(items);
  })
  .error(function () {...});
//...
```

Comment: I like the Promise solution! I have two providers which I will use either one or the other. I don't want to change the interface too much, so having the Promise to me looks more elegant than adding the callback.

Comment: Another nice thing about the promise solution is since it's a promise, you can use `.then` to transform the result before returning it from the service. `.then(function (result) {return transformResult(result);})`. It's really nice for methods such as `count`, so you can return a number rather than the object with a count property that is normally returned from a rest api.

Comment: indeed I will most probably need this feature as I need to filter that data! Most welcomed addition, thanks!